# Angular2 Ng Date Time picker too huge when opened

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am using Ng Date Time picker with Angular2 frontend from:
https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/?utm_source=recordnotfound.com
I tried to copy&paste the examples from here:
https://stackblitz.com/github/DanielYKPan/owl-examples/tree/date-time-picker?file=src%2Fmain.ts

into my component html file. I am using the ngx-admin template.

However, when I start my component and click inside the input field to open the date picker, the layout is kind of "messed up" and too huge across the window on the left side(see screenshot):

[image: Datepicker too big (left side)]

But I don't see any error in my code... heres my template:

```
 <label class="example-input-wrapper">
    Date Time:
    <input placeholder="Date Time:"
           [(ngModel)]="dateTime"
           [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt" [owlDateTime]="dt">
    <owl-date-time #dt></owl-date-time>
</label>
```

component.ts:

```
public dateTime: Date;
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FlexibilitiesComponent } from './flexibilities.component';
import { ThemeModule } from '../../@theme/theme.module';
import { NgxEchartsModule } from "ngx-echarts";
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import { DlDateTimePickerDateModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker';
import { AngularDateTimePickerModule } from 'angular2-datetimepicker';
import { NguiDatetimePickerModule } from '@ngui/datetime-picker';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ThemeModule,
    NgxEchartsModule,
    NgxChartsModule,
    DlDateTimePickerDateModule,
    AngularDateTimePickerModule,
    NguiDatetimePickerModule,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
    MomentModule,
  ],
  declarations: [FlexibilitiesComponent] 
})
export class FlexibilitiesModule { }
```

At stackblitz, they used more modules, but I don't know if they are app-specific or required to run the datetime picker...:

```
import { BasicComponent } from './basic/basic.component';
import { StandAloneComponent } from './stand-alone/stand-alone.component';
import { RangeComponent } from './range/range.component';
import { StartViewComponent } from './start-view/start-view.component';
import { ValidationComponent } from './validation/validation.component';
import { RestrictionComponent } from './restriction/restriction.component';
import { LocalizationComponent } from './localization/localization.component';
import { MomentJsComponent } from './moment-js/moment-js.component';
```

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this solution:

add `@import "~ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css";` in style.scss

Comment: well, I don't have a global style.css in my ngx-admin template...I added it in my component's css file, but it didn't work either :(

Comment: find "src/app/@theme/styles/styles.scss" and try to import here

Comment: wow a huge thx, that solved my problem indeed :) just a question besides... can I also add additional arbitrary general styles there like  angular material style templates? or normalize.css?

Answer (score 1):

add `@import "~ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css";`

in styles.scss in `src` folder

if you don't have this one, you can define it in angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
           ]}
            ...
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            ...
}
```